# How to install the C++ binding for ZeroMQ on Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, zeromq

On

```
g++ actualApp.cpp -lzmq
```

I get

```
actualApp.cpp:6:19: error: zmq.hpp: No such file or directory
actualApp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
actualApp.cpp:13: error: ‘zmq’ has not been declared
actualApp.cpp:13: error: expected `;' before ‘context’
actualApp.cpp:14: error: ‘zmq’ has not been declared
actualApp.cpp:14: error: expected `;' before ‘socket’
actualApp.cpp:15: error: ‘socket’ was not declared in this scope
actualApp.cpp:18: error: ‘zmq’ has not been declared
actualApp.cpp:18: error: expected `;' before ‘request’
actualApp.cpp:21: error: ‘request’ was not declared in this scope
actualApp.cpp:28: error: ‘zmq’ has not been declared
actualApp.cpp:28: error: expected `;' before ‘reply’
actualApp.cpp:29: error: ‘reply’ was not declared in this scope
actualApp.cpp: At global scope:
actualApp.cpp:33: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion at end of input
```

for

```
//
//  Hello World server in C++
//  Binds REP socket to tcp://*:5555
//  Expects "Hello" from client, replies with "World"
//
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main () {
    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
    socket.bind ("tcp://*:5555");

    while (true) {
        zmq::message_t request;

        //  Wait for next request from client
        socket.recv (&request);
        std::cout << "Received Hello" << std::endl;

        //  Do some 'work'
        sleep (1);

        //  Send reply back to client
        zmq::message_t reply (5);
        memcpy ((void *) reply.data (), "World", 5);
        socket.send (reply);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have installed zeromq on Mac OS X like this - `./configure`, `make`, `make install`.

I can compile the C examples without errors using the `-lzmq` flag.

How should I use this C++ `.hpp` header from https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq?

Comment: How do you compile the c++ code?

Comment: I did the C like this - gcc actualApp.c -lzmq

Comment: I was trying for c++ - g++ actualApp.cpp -lzmq

Answer (score 7):

I moved the file zmq.hpp to /usr/local/include where zmq.h was also there

Answer (score 5):

> How should I use this .hpp https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq file?

1. Download the CPP binding (which is just zmq.hpp header file) from the above link.
2. Make sure to include this header file while compiling. ex: g++  yourfile.cpp -I(path to zmq.hpp) -lzmq

Comment: Why is the .hpp header not included in the tarball?

Answer (score 3):

You have not provided a path to the include files and the lib folder if libzmq.so is in another folder. You need to use

`g++ actualApp.cpp -I$(Path to ZMQ include files) -L$(Path to ZMQ library files) -lzmq`

You probably also want to give `-o outFileName` unless you want your executable to be named `a.out`

Comment: I moved both the header and source file to /usr/local/include and it still says 'fatal error: no such file or directory' : `g++ asyncserver.cpp -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/include -lzmq -o asyncserver`

Answer (score 2):

My recipe using Homebrew (2.1.11) with Xcode (10.3).

**Step 1**

Install ZMQ (4.3.2) from Homebrew

```
brew install zeromq
```

**Step 2**

Clone cppzmq from GitHub

```
git clone https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq.git
```

**Step 3: Optional**

Build and test cppzmq.

```
cd /path/to/cppzmq
./ci_build.sh
```

**Step 4**

Set up Xcode project.

1. Copy `cppzmp/zmq.hpp` to `/usr/local/include`
2. Add `/usr/local/include` to `Header Search Path` of `Build Settings`
3. Find out proper flags: `pkg-config --libs libzmq`. Put the result into `Other Linker Flags` of `Build Settings`
4. Add `#include <zmq.hpp>` to your source file.
5. Build your Xcode project.

Answer (score 1):

Add /usr/local/include to your search path